# How to increase width of lines in Primefaces line chart

Tags: primefaces

How to increase width of lines in Primefaces line chart? I want to increase width of line in line charts , but there is no option in  tag

Answer (score 0):

Charts in Primefaces are based on [jqPlot](http://www.jqplot.com/). For options that are not accessible by the Chart API you have to use the "Extender".
E.g. if you want to set the color and line width for all series you have to create a Javascript function with the extended configuration for your chart:

```
function myLineChartExtender() {
  // this = chart widget instance
  // this.cfg = jqPlot options
  this.cfg.seriesDefaults = {
    color: "#000000",
    lineWidth: 10.0
  }
}
```

Then you have to specify the extender:

*Primefaces 5.0 and later:*

Specify the name of the Javascript function when you initialize the model:

```
LineChartModel model = new LineChartModel();
...
model.setExtender("myLineChartExtender");
```

*Primefaces before 5.0:*

Specify the name of the Javascript function as XHTML parameter:

```
<p:chart type="line" model="#{bean.model}" extender="myLineChartExtender" />
```

See [jqPlot Options Tutorial](http://www.jqplot.com/docs/files/optionsTutorial-txt.html) for further explanation on how to use the options. A list of all options can be found [here](http://www.jqplot.com/docs/files/jqplot-core-js.html).